# c++ Writing callback function in file.h and file.cpp

Tags: c++, windows, callback

I need to write a callback function because I will be using the following function:

```
EnumChildWindows(windowHandle, EnumChildProc, 0);
```

where the second variable "EnumChildProc" needs to be a callback function.

The problem is that I am having difficulties when writing the function in both the header and source file. Normally when I write a boolean function or any other type, I would first delcare it in the header the following way:

```
bool myFunction(int var1);
```

and if the previous file was in file.h, I would then write the following code in the source file:

```
bool file::myFunction (int var1)
{
  ///here would be my code
}
```

but with a callback function I tried doing the following and it didn't work:

in the file.h:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM lParam);
```

in the file.cpp:

```
BOOL file::CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM lParam)
{
   ///code goes here
}
```

It doesnt work because I get the following error:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before '__attribute__'
```

and the error refers to the following line in the source code:

```
BOOL programLoop::CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM lParam)
```

any ideas what I am doing wrong? I don't know if I am doing something wrong when I declare the callback function in the header or source file or somewhere... what do you guys think?

Comment: You don't need to prefix the function definition in the cpp with `file::`. When you define a class *member function*, you need to prefix it with `classname::`; the classname may be (and often is) the same as the filname, but it doesn't have to be. Your callback is a free function, so it doesn't need any scoping (except in special circumstances involving namespaces). Also, if the callback function isn't referenced from other files, you don't need to declare it in the .h at all.

Comment: Ok... and what is the difference between a "class member function" and a "free function". I just write down the file:: always but didn't even understand it's purpose

Comment: @dlf oh and there is a problem if I don't declare it in the file.h... it doesn't seem to get the variables I declared in the public section of the file.h header... what do you think about that?

Comment: A free function is just a function that is not a member of any class. Languages like C# and Java don't allow this, but C++ does. Any callback function you use with something like EnumChildWindows must be either a free function or a static member function. This implies that you won't be able to get to any class member variables from within the callback function without doing some extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CALLBACK is just a macro that adds a specialized Microsoft attribute to to a function declaration.   Use it ONLY in a declaration, not where you use the function.

The second parameter of EnumChildWindows is declared as a `WNDENUMPROC`, which is declared as

```
    typedef BOOL (CALLBACK* WNDENUMPROC)(HWND, LPARAM);
```

so you would declare your callback function as

```
    BOOL CALLBACK myFunction (HWND w, LPARAM var1);
```

or

```
    BOOL CALLBACK file::myFunction (HWND w, LPARAM var1);
```

The scope qualifier `::` *always* comes right between the scope name (in this case `file`) and the dependent name (`myFunction`)

If `file` is a namespace then you're all set; if `file` is a class remember to also declare myFunction `static` in the class.  You may also need `extern` in certain circumstances.

When you enumerate child windows

```
    HWND hwparent=/* handle of the window you want to enumerate */;
    LPARAM var1=/* the value you want to pass in*/;

    EnumChildWindows (hwParent, myFunction, var1);
```

Windows calls your function for each window, passing the `w` parameter in so you know which window it is and `var1` which is your parameter.

---

As for where: It is not necessary to declare `myFunction` in the header file.  Most likely *only the call to `EnumChildWindows`* uses `myFunction`.  It's not going to be called from any other file.  So you're OK as long as `myFunction` comes before the call to `EnumChildWindows` in the .cpp file.

Of course, if `file` is a class, then the static member function `myFunction` has to be inside the class declaration, which usually goes in a header somewhere.

When you use the function, you only need to add `file::` if the place you call it from is not already in the `file` (class or namespace) scope.

If `file` is a class you need `file::` where you define myFunction, but don't need `file::` if you're calling `EnumChildWindows` in another class member function.

```
  // .h file

  class file 
  { 
   private:

   HWND m_hwParent;

   static HRESULT myFunction (HWND hw, LPARAM arg1); 

   public:

   HRESULT OnAllChildWindows (LPARAM arg1);

   // more stuff
  };

  // .cpp file 

  HRESULT file::myFunction (HWND hw, LPARAM arg1) 
  {
   // whatever this does
  }

  HRESULT file::OnAllChildWindows (LPARAM arg1)
  {
   EnumChildWindows (m_hwParent, myFunction, arg1);
  }
```

If `file` is a namespace you don't need `file::` if you wrapped all your code in a namespace block:

```
  namespace file {

      HRESULT myFunction (HWND hw, LPARAM arg1) 
      {
       // whatever this does
      }

      HRESULT OnAllChildWindows (HWND hwParent, LPARAM arg1)
      {
       EnumChildWindows (myFunction, arg1);
      }
   }
```

but if you didn't, or if it's a different scope:

```
  HRESULT someting_else::OnAllChildWindows (HWND hwParent, LPARAM arg1)
  {
   EnumChildWindows (hwParent, file::myFunction, arg1);
  }
```

Comment: ok awesome, so that is how I declare it in the header file. How would you write it in the .cpp file... also with file::myFunction or differently? (show example code if you can pls)

Comment: Too long for a comment so I'm adding it to my answer.